# Omitting "ser" or "estar" in "Llamada finalizada"

Tags: gramática

After ending Skype call, I noticed there was written:

*Llamada finalizada*

Questions:

1) Wouldn't it be correct to say like this?

*Llamada es finalizada* [passive voice]

OR

*Llamada está finalizada* [estar + adjective]

My guess that "llamada finalizada" is formed by simply omitting "ser" or "estar". But is it correct? In case it is correct, please explain the differences in meaning between three:

*Llamada finalizada*

*Llamada es finalizada*

*Llamada está finalizada*

In one movie (translated from Spanish to English) I also heard the following sequence of sentences (it was during attacking other submarine)

*Torpedos están listos para armarse*

And then: *Torpedos armados* [while correct would be to use "están" in between]

My confusion stems from the fact that it is the same in English - if you use "to be" before past participle, you should use it also in Spanish:

*Call is finished = llamada es finalizada*

But I can imagine that in English sometimes "to be" is omitted and we have the following in the end:

*Torpedoes armed, Sir - Torpedos armados.*

Similar to what I heard in other movie:

*- Hazlo, por favor.*

*- Already done = Ya hecho* [instead of longer: "*It is done already*" = "*ya es hecho*"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures like:

1) Llamada finalizada (Call completed)

and

2) Torpedos armados (Torpedoes armed)

are only used for short announcements in writing or in speech. They are used to  describe the current state of things.

1) comes from:

1') La llamada está finalizada. (The call is finished.)

(*La llamada es finalizada* is only used when reference is made to the action of ending the call, not to the current completed state. However, "es finalizada" sounds awkward in this case and we would use intransitive "finalizar": *La llamada es finalizada transcurridos tres minutos -> (much better) La llamada finaliza transcurridos tres minutos.*)

2) comes from:

2') Los torpedos están armados (The topedoes are armed.)

We say: "Los torpedos son armados" to refer to the action of getting them ready for attack, not to their condition of being ready as expressed by (2').

Comment: Everything understood except "La llamada es finalizada transcurridos tres minutos" OR "La llamada finaliza transcurridos tres minutos." Don't you better use here future tense for something that will be finished in several minutes? Like in English: "Call will end in 3 minutes?" Even though I know that in both English and Spanish you can use present to state future actions ("call ends in 3 minutes"). Is it like this here with ser + past participle?

Comment: @Alex La llamada es finalizada/finaliza transcurridos tres minutos refers to the standard time calls last (present tense). After 3 minutes, the call is interrupted (a method used in some companies to prevent people talking for too long).